# Pandas: Rank item across columns

Tags: python, pandas

I'm encountering an error trying to rank across columns in Pandas.  This code snippet runs perfectly well, ranks 'col a' against itself (eg AAPL col A is the smallest amongst peer col A).

```
df1 = df[['col a', 'col b', 'col c']]
df1 = df1[:5]
df1['rank'] = df1['col a'].rank(axis=0)
print(df1)

             col a          col b          col c      rank 
ticker                                                   
AAPL         0.336250       0.277405       0.243450   1.0
GOOGL        0.536069       0.545514       0.538530   2.5
GOOG         0.536069       0.545514       0.538530   2.5
MSFT         0.546128       0.886630       0.601523   4.0
BRK.B        0.695393       0.738491       0.753857   5.0
```

**I want to rank AAPL `col a` against AAPL `['col a', 'col b', 'col c']`.**
The result for AAPL would be 3.0.

The Pandas documentation suggests (to me at least) that you can set the `axis=1` to rank across columns.  However, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: No axis named 1 for object type <class pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

(note: I also get an error setting the 'axis=columns')

```
df1 = df[['col a', 'col b', 'col c']]
df1 = df1[:5]
df1['rank'] = df1['col a'].rank(axis=1)
print(df1)
```

Relevant Pandas documentation

- *DataFrame.rank(axis=0, method='average', numeric_only=None, na_option='keep', ascending=True, pct=False)*
- *axis: {0 or ‘index’, 1 or ‘columns’}, default 0 index to direct
  ranking*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are making a key error in understanding pandas. When you write `df1['col a']` you have selected a single column and now have a pandas Series. Pandas Series have only one axis (axis 0) and do not have a horizontal axis like dataframes do. What you can do is use rank with your entire dataframe and then select the ranking of `col a` like this.

```
df['rank'] = df.rank(axis=1)['col a']
```

#### Output

```
           col a     col b     col c  rank
ticker                                    
AAPL    0.336250  0.277405  0.243450   3.0
GOOGL   0.536069  0.545514  0.538530   1.0
GOOG    0.536069  0.545514  0.538530   1.0
MSFT    0.546128  0.886630  0.601523   1.0
BRK.B   0.695393  0.738491  0.753857   1.0
```

#### Using numpy

numpy does something similar for you with `argsort`. It will be a little faster.

```
np.argsort(df).add(1)['col a']
```

#### Further discussion on axis

The following `df1['col a'].rank(axis=0)` works because even though `df1['col a']` returns a series because its one and only axis is referred to as `0`. This should strike you as strange that you would even need to declare what axis to choose for Series operations and in fact I don't know of any reason why to use the `axis` parameter for Series. I'm a little surprised that pandas even has this parameter available for Series methods. Maybe someone else can enlighten us as to why the `axis` parameter exists for Series as I have never used it or seen it used.

Comment: Thanks for the response Ted and the additional explanation.  The Series vs Dataframe and corresponding methods is helpful.  Your response solved the error.